# Escape sequences interrupt pyserial client

Tags: python, terminal, serial-port, pyserial, ansi-escape

I'm writing a client for a networking device using `pyserial` which hangs for a couple of seconds after logging into the device and before getting a prompt on the device. Tracing the bytes over the line I see the following escape sequences are the cause of the hold up:

```
0003a0  73 65 20 6c 65 76 65 6c  0d 0a 0d 1b 5b 39 39 39       |se level....[999|
0003b0  39 42 0d 1b 5b 39 39 39  39 42 1b 5a 20 20 1b 5b       |9B..[9999B.Z  .[|
0003c0  36 6e 0d 0d 0d 0d 5b 61  64 6d 69 6e 40 73 77 69       |6n....[admin@swi|
0003d0  74 63 68 5d 20 3e 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20       |tch] >          |
```

When using `screen` to connect to the device, no delay is seen as `screen` is responding appropriately.

```
0003a0  73 65 20 6c 65 76 65 6c  0d 0a 0d 1b 5b 39 39 39       |se level....[999|
0003b0  39 42 0d 1b 5b 39 39 39  39 42 1b 5a 20                |9B..[9999B.Z    |

                                ---=== WRITE ===---
000000  1b 5b 3f 31 3b 32 63                                   |.[?1;2c         |

                                ---=== READ ===---
000000  20 1b 5b 36 6e                                         | .[6n           |

                                ---=== WRITE ===---
000000  1b 5b 35 37 3b 33 52                                   |.[57;3R         |

                                ---=== READ ===---
000000  1b 5b 34 6c 1b 5b 32 30  6c 1b 5b 3f 34 37 6c 1b       |.[4l.[20l.[?47l.|
000010  5b 3f 37 68 1b 5b 3f 35  6c 1b 5b 3f 32 35 68 1b       |[?7h.[?5l.[?25h.|
000020  5b 48 1b 5b 39 39 39 39  42 1b 5b 36 6e                |[H.[9999B.[6n   |

                                ---=== WRITE ===---
000000  1b 5b 35 37 3b 31 52                                   |.[57;1R         |

                                ---=== READ ===---
000000  1b 5b 48 1b 5b 39 39 39  39 42 1b 44 1b 5b 39 39       |.[H.[9999B.D.[99|
000010  39 39 41 1b 5b 36 6e                                   |99A.[6n         |

                                ---=== WRITE ===---
000000  1b 5b 31 3b 31 52                                      |.[1;1R          |

                                ---=== READ ===---
000000  1b 5b 48 1b 5b 39 39 39  39 43 1b 5b 36 6e             |.[H.[9999C.[6n  |

                                ---=== WRITE ===---
000000  1b 5b 31 3b 31 34 31 52                                |.[1;141R        |

                                ---=== READ ===---
000000  1b 5b 48 c4 9b 48 1b 5b  36 6e 0d 20 20 20             |.[H..H.[6n.     |

                                ---=== WRITE ===---
000000  1b 5b 31 3b 33 52                                      |.[1;3R          |

                                ---=== READ ===---
000000  1b 5b 48 1b 5b 39 39 39  39 43 1b 5b 36 6e 20 1b       |.[H.[9999C.[6n .|

                                ---=== WRITE ===---
000000  1b 5b 31 3b 31 34 31 52                                |.[1;141R        |

                                ---=== READ ===---
000000  5b 36 6e 20 1b 5b 36 6e                                |[6n .[6n        |

                                ---=== WRITE ===---
000000  1b 5b 31 3b 31 34 32 52  1b 5b 32 3b 32 52             |.[1;142R.[2;2R  |

                                ---=== READ ===---
000000  1b 5b 33 3b 35 72 1b 5b  48 1b 5b 36 6e 0a 0a          |.[3;5r.[H.[6n.. |
                               ---=== WRITE ===---
000000  1b 5b 31 3b 31 52                                      |.[1;1R          |

                                ---=== READ ===---
000000  0a 0a 0a 0a 0a 1b 5b 36  6e 1b 5b                      |......[6n.[     |

                                ---=== WRITE ===---
000000  1b 5b 35 3b 31 52                                      |.[5;1R          |

                                ---=== READ ===---
000000  39 39 39 39 42 1b 5b 36  6e 1b 5b 72                   |9999B.[6n.[r    |

                                ---=== WRITE ===---
000000  1b 5b 35 3b 31 52                                      |.[5;1R          |

                                ---=== READ ===---
000000  1b 5b 31 3b 39 39 39 39  72 0d 0d 0d 1b 5b 39 39       |.[1;9999r....[99|
000010  39 39 42 5b 61 64 6d 69  6e 40 73 77 69 74 63 68       |99B[admin@switch|
000020  5d 20 3e 20                                            |] >             |
```

What exactly is this series of escape sequences doing, and what is the best way to handle this in my client?

```
from asyncio import Protocol, get_event_loop
from serial.aio import create_serial_connection

class Serial(Protocol):

   def connection_made(self, transport):
       self.transport = transport

   def data_received(self, data):
       self.buffer += data.decode("utf-8")
       self.handle()

   def send(self, line):
       self.transport.write("{}\r\n".format(line).encode())

loop = get_event_loop()
coro = create_serial_connection(loop, Serial, "/dev/ttyUSB0")
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: It may be worthwhile to try to tell the device on the other side that the local client doesn't understand those escape sequences, so the device doesn't send them. Maybe there's a way to configure there terminal type or the TERM environment variable? The other side most likely expects an _xterm_ or _vt100_ or similar terminal right now.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to tell the device not to send the sequences however I was interested in finding out some more about the process.

Comment: Well, if you can somehow detect the escape sequence and send an appropriate answer, that would likely work, too, and would likely solve the pausing issue. The relevant standard is [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm).

Comment: Right, but I didn't want to arbitrarily replay the esc codes I'd captured with strace. I would think numerous libraries exist that I could make use of here.

Comment: To me, that sounds difficult to do for a library in a robust and comprehensive way, as it basically amounts to a hybrid of terminal emulation (which would handle the escape codes) and line based request-response (which I believe is what you want to do, unless I'm misunderstanding it). Of course that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. It's just my gut feeling.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of ncurses, terminfo, termios ect.

Comment: Well, those libraries are meant for an application to use when it's talking to a terminal like console, like a real terminal or a terminal emulator.

In your case that would apply to the application that's running on the remote device when you're connecting to it with a standard communication program like PuTTY or minicom.

It would not apply to your client application that you're writing, as this one is going to talk to the remote device's application instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That chunk with `[6n` (and the escape character preceding it) is asking the *terminal* to tell it where the cursor is, as part of determining the screensize.  Apparently `pyserial` doesn't understand that, and you have to wait a while for the program doing the asking to give up and continue.

In [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html):

```
CSI Ps n  Device Status Report (DSR).
...
            Ps = 6  -> Report Cursor Position (CPR) [row;column].
```

where *CSI* is the control sequence initiator <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>**`[`**</kbd>.

When you run `screen`, it [*interprets*](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/ansi.c#n1033) this control sequence (i.e., it *reads*, *understands* and *replies* appropriately):

```
        case 'n':
            if (a1 == 5)    /* Report terminal status */
                Report(win, "\033[0n", 0, 0);
            else if (a1 == 6)   /* Report cursor position */
                Report(win, "\033[%d;%dR", win->w_y + 1, win->w_x + 1);
```

The status report control sequence is used by a few programs such as `resize` to determine the size of your terminal's screen.  It works by moving the cursor to an impossibly far lower-right-corner, and then (because terminals have limits) asking how far it got. This particular example is not using `resize`, which sends [**`999`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/master/resize.c#L136) for each coordinate (but it's debatable whether there's a real scenario where four digits are needed).

The application that is sending the device status control sequence moves the cursor *down* with the <kbd>*escape*</kbd><kbd>**`[9999B`**</kbd>, and apparently uses that later when setting up scrolling margins with the sequence ending with **`r`**. This is a frequently-used VT100 feature **not** in [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm) (the **`r`** denotes a *private use* sequence, i.e., not standardized).

If you give it a bogus value for the cursor position, you might get poor results.

It also tries with two *different* control sequences to move the cursor to the home (upper-left) in this sequence from the `screen` read/writes:

```
1b 5b 48 c4 9b 48
```

(`0x9b` is the 8-bit equivalent of `0x1b`, `0x5b` or <kbd>*escape*</kbd><kbd>**`[`**</kbd>).

So your choices are few:

- eliminate the (possibly unnecessary) query for screen-size, or
- modify your pyserial script to handle the device status control sequence